# Splitting the project into dependent parts

Tags: python

I want to split a large project into several directories where the code intersects. For example, I want to separate data from some stuff:

```
.
|- data
|  |- __init__.py
|  \- data.py
\- some_stuff
   |- __init__.py
   \- some_stuff.py
```

And, of course, `some_stuff` depends on `data`.
How to import `data` from `some_stuff` correctly with this approach and how to organize the code in each directory correctly for this, what should I write in `data/__init__.py` and `some_stuff/__init__.py`?